# Tenho que fazer um login para que cada vez que alguém se registrar ele criar automaticamente um id, com números diferentes. Código a baixo:

Tags: javascript

### **HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <!--Meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
    iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" 
    crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <!--Bootstrap Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap- 
    icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!--Fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Rubik:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--JS-->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="ResuFinal ColorResu"> </p>
        <div class="child d-inline-block">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="i1" placeholder="Digite seu Nome..." 
                name="input1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="i2" placeholder="Digite seu Estado..." 
                name="input2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6" id="input3">
                <p class="h5">Data de nascimento:</p>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inputDate" min="1910-01-01" 
                max="2022-12-12" placeholder="Digite seu Estado...">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button onclick="Enviar(resultado)" class="btn btn-success" 
                id="button">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### **JAVASCRIPT**

```
let Nome = document.getElementsByName("input1");
let Estado = document.getElementsByName("input2");
let Data = document.getElementsByName("inputDate");

function Enviar(resultado) {
    if(Nome.values && Estado.values && Data.values != undefined) {
        for(let x=0;x<=10;x++) {
            resultado = document.getElementById("ResuFinal").innerHTML = 
            "Cadastro concluído!!\n" +
            "Seu nome é " + Nome.values + ", seu estado é " +
            Estado.values + ", sua data de nascimento é " +
            Data.values + " e seu id é 0" + x + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar uma função pra gerar esse id pra vc:

```
function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
  );
}
```

Hoje se usa muito o uuid mas vc poder usar outras técnicas também, daí é só chamar a função e colocar o valor de retorno no id do seu usuário.

```
const id = uuidv4();
```